# bash: use outside variables when reading multiple lines into ssh

Tags: mysql, bash

I apologize if the title doesn't quite describe what I'm looking for.  Please edit if possible.

I have a bash script that does the following:

```
serveruser="root"
serverip=1.2.3.4
serverpath="/var/www"


ssh "$serveruser"@"$serverip" /bin/bash <<\EOF
mkdir -p "$serverpath/mysqldumps/"
cd "$serverpath/mysqldumps/"
domainname=somedomain.com
mysqldump -h 192.168.1.4 -udba -ppassword -c --add-drop-table --add-locks --create-options --databases --quick --lock-tables $domainname > $domainname.sql
EOF
```

My problem is that the multiple lines I am "feeding" to ssh don't parse the variables I set before.  This is obviously because the variables aren't set on the remote machine, only in my local shell.  How could I pass these variables or possibly pass multiple lines to ssh in a different way?

Comment: Why not do it the other way as in `echo "cmd $var | ssh user@remote bash`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way you're escaping the here-doc word is preventing variable substitution. Contrast

```
cat <<\END
$PATH
$LOGNAME
END
```

versus

```
cat <<END
$PATH
$LOGNAME
END
```

---

**update**

On closer inspection, I see you're setting a variable in the heredoc. That should *not* be expanded on the local machine, so you need to escape those in the mysqldump command.  Try this:

```
ssh "$serveruser"@"$serverip" <<EOF
mkdir -p "$serverpath/mysqldumps/"
cd "$serverpath/mysqldumps/"
domainname=somedomain.com
mysqldump -h 192.168.1.4 -udba -ppassword -c --add-drop-table --add-locks --create-options --databases --quick --lock-tables \$domainname > \$domainname.sql
EOF
```

Comment: For some reason I get strange things happening when I don't use the backslash.  For example, my shell seems to pause for over a minute and I get an error later on that mysql can't connect to the server, as if the commands were actually running locally and not on the remote ssh server.  I have verified that within the here-doc setting the serverpath var works as expected.  I need to be able to set out outside of that here-doc though.

Comment: What's happening is that you're logging on to the remote server, running bash **non-interactively**, and that exits right away. Then the commands in the heredoc get executed. Simply remove "/bin/bash" from the ssh command and it will execute the heredoc remotely.

Comment: I added /bin/bash to ssh because without it I get the error: Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
That error doesn't seem to actually break anything though.

Comment: Use the ssh options `-t` or `-T` to force/disable a pseudo-tty, depending on your needs. That will at least take care of the error message.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about -T.  At first I thought removing /bin/bash solved my problems... but on further testing it's still not expanding the variables within the heredoc.

Comment: This did it.  One must escape the remotely created variables like \$variablename, while simply referring to a $variable expands it from your local shell.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
remote_user_name=user
instance_ip=127.0.0.1
external=$(ls /home/)

ssh -T -i ${private_key}  -l ${remote_user_name} ${instance_ip} << END
  internal=\$(ls /home/)
  echo "\${internal}"
  echo "${external}"
END
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to quote the whole command.. and no need to quote the vars like that put them like ${var}

```
serveruser="root"
serverip=1.2.3.4
serverpath="/var/www"


ssh ${serveruser}@${serverip} "/bin/bash <<\EOF
mkdir -p ${serverpath}/mysqldumps/
cd ${serverpath}/mysqldumps/
EOF"
```

Comment: I always quote just based on info like : http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#cp_.24file_.24target .

Comment: $( ) runs its inner commands in a subshell, so referring to any variable like that doesn't seem to work in bash.